# Как воспроизвести видео из CoreData в формате NSData в проигрывателе AVPlayer?

Tags: xcode, swift

Здравствуйте! У меня находится видео (точнее gif небольшого объема) в Core Data в формате Binary Data, изначально формат был mp4. По тз нельзя засорять галерею и чтобы там был хоть какой то мусор, то что воспроизведение будет задержками роли не играет. Главный вопрос, как воспроизвести видео в AVPlayer, на многих форумах ответа не дали и не смогли решить проблему, осталась надежда только на этот форум.

Comment: что именно вызывает затруднение?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko весь процесс воспроизведения, я разархивирую допустим сами видео файлы и как передать их в AVPlayer?

Comment: у AVPlayer есть методы initWithUrl и initWithPlayerItem.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko есть, но формат data он не поддерживает

Comment: вы же говорите вызывает затруднение передать файлы в AVPlayer. а окзывается вызывает затруднение сконвертировать NSData обратно в mp4. Можете сохранить свои данные в формате mp4 в кэш и передать url в плеер

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko это я умею делать, мне интересно для общего развития как из CoreData воспроизвести. Т.е. видео загружено и хранится в binary data, как переконвертировать или что-то еще сделать для того, чтобы воспроизвести?